# Optimal settings for auto-complete for writing papers / prose in natural language?

Tags: auto-complete-mode, writing

As the question suggest, I am trying to set up the [`auto-complete`](http://auto-complete.org/) package for writing papers. I have also installed [`ac-ispell`](https://github.com/syohex/emacs-ac-ispell). So far it seems more or less useless, mostly because it is **way too slow**. Suggestions take several full seconds to appear.

Here are the relevant lines that I currently have in my init, which are based directly on the recommendations in the documentation for these two packages:

```el
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)
(add-to-list 'ac-modes '(org-mode text-mode LaTeX-mode))

(custom-set-variables
 '(ac-ispell-requires 4)
 '(ac-ispell-fuzzy-limit 2))

(eval-after-load "auto-complete"
  '(progn
     (ac-ispell-setup)))

(add-hook 'git-commit-mode-hook 'ac-ispell-ac-setup)
(add-hook 'mail-mode-hook 'ac-ispell-ac-setup)
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'ac-ispell-ac-setup)
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'ac-ispell-ac-setup)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'ac-ispell-ac-setup)

(global-auto-complete-mode t)
```

In case this helps, the resulting value for `ac-sources` is `(ac-source-ispell ac-source-ispell-fuzzy ac-source-abbrev ac-source-dictionary ac-source-words-in-same-mode-buffers)`.

If you've had better luck with this then I have, please help!

Comment: I've now opened an issue for [company-mode](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/issues/425) with a very lengthy and detailed version of this question. If I get a good resolution, I will post it as an answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Predictive-mode](http://www.dr-qubit.org/predictive/predictive-user-manual/html/What-is-predictive-completion_003f.html#What-is-predictive-completion_003f) claims to be what you're looking for, though I'm not sure how it compares to more modern completion frameworks like [company-mode](http://company-mode.github.io/).

Comment: I haven't tried them yet, but these look like promising options, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

suppose you use company-mode and you only want to use it in text-mode. org-mode inherits from text-mode, so you don't need setup for both:

```el
(require 'company)
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)

(defun text-mode-hook-setup ()
  ;; make `company-backends' local is critcal
  ;; or else, you will have completion in every major mode, that's very annoying!
  (make-local-variable 'company-backends)

  ;; company-ispell is the plugin to complete words
  (add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-ispell)

  ;; OPTIONAL, if `company-ispell-dictionary' is nil, `ispell-complete-word-dict' is used
  ;;  but I prefer hard code the dictionary path. That's more portable.
  (setq company-ispell-dictionary (file-truename "~/.emacs.d/misc/english-words.txt")))

(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'text-mode-hook-setup)
```

"english-words.txt" is just a plain text file where lines sorted alphabetically. Every line is a word. (Plain text dictionary is required by `ispell`, see https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/42526/ for technical details).

Here is a sample file: https://github.com/redguardtoo/emacs.d/raw/master/misc/english-words.txt

Tested with Emacs24.3, 24.4, company-mode 0.8.12