# How to use an ispell dictionary in company mode?

Tags: company-mode, text-editing, ispell, writing

I am writing in LaTeX at the moment and I want to use `company-mode` for word completion. I found this solution: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/18522.

I was thinking about using the ispell dictionary instead, then I can also switch to another language for other documents.

I tried the code below, but when trying with `company-complete` I just get `No completion found` with almost any word.

```el
(require 'ispell)
(setq ispell-dictionary "en_US")

(require 'company)
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)
(add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-ispell)
(setq company-ispell-dictionary ispell-dictionary)
```

Does `company-ispell` only work with plain txt dictionaries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need provide a "plain word-list dictionary".

Step 1, Check the code of `company-ispell`, it actually calls `ispell-lookup-words`.

Step 2, check `ispell-lookup-words` documentation:

"Optional second argument contains the dictionary to use; **the default is
‘ispell-alternate-dictionary’**, overridden by ‘ispell-complete-word-dict’
if defined."

Step 3, check `ispell-alternate-dictionary` documentation:

"Alternate **plain word-list dictionary** for spelling help."

So **binary dictionaries** won't work.

BTW, Emacs will automatically find readable dictionary for `ispell-alternate-dictionary` on macOS/Linux. So usually you don't need any extra setup.

If you are using Windows, here is a sample dictionary: https://github.com/redguardtoo/emacs.d/blob/e9c656592d5ad89ee008764903972d0aeda2339b/misc/english-words.txt

Comment: Perfect explanation! Didn't come across the ispell-alternate-dictionary documentation. Thanks for helping me out! Seems that now I need to search for plain word-list dictionaries for my other languages.

Comment: Note that the word list needs to be sorted (case insensitive) I didn't see this documented anywhere, although I might have missed it. See this answer for an example configuration that generates the word-list: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/54742/2418