# Using company-ispell with large text dictionary?

Tags: company-mode, ispell

I've managed to setup `company-ispell` which seems to work for small files, but fails for a dump of the aspell dictionary.

This works when pressing `C-SPC` without any existing text before the cursor.

But when there is some text e.g. `wheel`, there is no completion found.

However when there is no prefix, there are multiple words starting with `wheel` in the list.

```el
(use-package company
  :commands (company-complete-common))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-SPC") 'company-complete-common)

(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (when (derived-mode-p 'text-mode)

      (company-mode)

      (make-local-variable 'company-backends)

      ;; company-ispell is the plugin to complete words
      (setq company-backends (list 'company-ispell))

      (setq ispell-complete-word-dict
        (expand-file-name (concat user-emacs-directory "aspell_words.txt")))

      (when (and ispell-complete-word-dict (not (file-exists-p ispell-complete-word-dict)))
        (shell-command (concat "aspell -d en_US dump master > " ispell-complete-word-dict))))))
```

In the `*Message*` buffer, there is output.

```
Starting "look" process...
No completion found
```

Checking the process monitor, there aren't any hanging background processes.

How can company-mode's `company-complete-common` be used to complete dictionary words?

Answer (score 4):

It turns out the word list needs to be sorted (case insensitive), at least sorting it makes it work for me.

Assuming you use company mode and have a shortcut to activate it.

```el
(use-package company
  :commands (company-complete-common))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-SPC") 'company-complete-common)
```

```el
;; Dictionary for completion.
(setq ispell-complete-word-dict
  (expand-file-name (concat user-emacs-directory "aspell_words.txt")))

(defun my-generic-ispell-company-complete-setup ()
  ;; Only apply this locally.
  (make-local-variable 'company-backends)
  (setq company-backends (list 'company-ispell))

  (when ispell-complete-word-dict
    (let*
      (
        (has-dict-complete
          (and ispell-complete-word-dict (file-exists-p ispell-complete-word-dict)))
        (has-dict-personal
          (and ispell-personal-dictionary (file-exists-p ispell-personal-dictionary)))
        (is-dict-outdated
          (and
            has-dict-complete has-dict-personal
            (time-less-p
              (nth 5 (file-attributes ispell-complete-word-dict))
              (nth 5 (file-attributes ispell-personal-dictionary))))))

      (when (or (not has-dict-complete) is-dict-outdated)
        (with-temp-buffer

          ;; Optional: insert personal dictionary, stripping header and inserting a newline.
          (when has-dict-personal
            (insert-file-contents ispell-personal-dictionary)
            (goto-char (point-min))
            (when (looking-at "personal_ws\-")
              (delete-region (line-beginning-position) (1+ (line-end-position))))
            (goto-char (point-max))
            (unless (eq ?\n (char-after))
              (insert "\n")))

          (call-process "aspell" nil t nil "-d" "en_US" "dump" "master")
          ;; Case insensitive sort is important for the lookup.
          (let ((sort-fold-case t))
            (sort-lines nil (point-min) (point-max)))
          (write-region nil nil ispell-complete-word-dict))))))

;; Enable this in appropriate modes.

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (my-generic-ispell-company-complete-setup)))
(add-hook 'rst-mode-hook (lambda () (my-generic-ispell-company-complete-setup)))
(add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook (lambda () (my-generic-ispell-company-complete-setup)))
```